# Sphere are overlapping even tho I check for collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using this code to generate a number of sphere around a center point, with different size and position.

There is a conditional check to prevent sphere from overlapping.

The problem I face is, in the scene some sphere are always overlapping.

=>

```
[Header("Galaxy")]
public int numberOfStars = 300;
public int maximumRadius = 100;
public float minDistBetweenStars = 2f;
[Header("Star")]
public float minimumSize = 1f;
public float maximumSize = 2f;

void Start()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
    {
        float distance = Random.Range(0, maximumRadius);
        float angle = Random.Range(0, 2 * Mathf.PI);

        float starSize = Random.Range(minimumSize, maximumSize);
        Vector3 starPosition = new Vector3(distance * Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, distance * Mathf.Sin(angle));

        Collider[] starCollider = Physics.OverlapSphere(starPosition, (starSize * 0.5f) + minDistBetweenStars);
        if (starCollider.Length == 0)
        {
            GameObject star = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            star.transform.position = starPosition;
            star.transform.localScale = new Vector3(starSize, starSize, starSize);
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

I do pass in the remove, so some sphere are being removed,m but I still see a lot of overlapping.

Comment: okey so im testing this thing for like 30 minutes now, and im starting to think that `Physics.OverlapSphere` is broken cos it returns all of the colliders sometimes, even tho they are like 100f away strange, do you accept another solution that is not based on `Physics.OverlapSphere` ?

Comment: @Menyus look my updated code ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was we were not disabling the collider on the sphere we was checking :P

```
public class StarGenSO : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Galaxy")]
    public int numberOfStars = 300;
    public int maximumRadius = 100;
    public float minDistBetweenStars = 2f;
    [Header("Star")]
    public float minimumSize = 1f;
    public float maximumSize = 2f;

    void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
        {
            GameObject star = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);

            float distance = Random.Range(0, maximumRadius);
            float angle = Random.Range(0, 2 * Mathf.PI);

            float starSize = Random.Range(minimumSize, maximumSize);
            Vector3 starPosition = new Vector3(distance * Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, distance * Mathf.Sin(angle));

            var currentCol = star.GetComponent<Collider>();
            currentCol.enabled = false;

            Collider[] starCollider = Physics.OverlapSphere(starPosition, (starSize * 0.5f) + minDistBetweenStars);
            if (starCollider.Length == 0)
            {
                star.transform.position = starPosition;
                star.transform.localScale = new Vector3(starSize, starSize, starSize);
                currentCol.enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("remove");
                Destroy(star);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A preferred solution**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StarGenSo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Galaxy")]
    public int numberOfStars = 300;
    public int maximumRadius = 100;
    public float minDistBetweenStars = 2f;
    [Header("Star")]
    public float minimumSize = 1f;
    public float maximumSize = 2f;
    [Header("Star Object")]
    public GameObject obj;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
        {
            float distance = Random.Range(0, maximumRadius);
            float angle = Random.Range(0, 2 * Mathf.PI);

            float starSize = Random.Range(minimumSize, maximumSize);
            Vector3 starPosition = new Vector3(distance * Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, distance * Mathf.Sin(angle));

            Collider[] starCollider = Physics.OverlapSphere(starPosition, (starSize * 0.5f) + minDistBetweenStars);
            if (starCollider.Length == 0)
            {
                GameObject star = Instantiate(obj);
                star.transform.position = starPosition;
                star.transform.localScale = new Vector3(starSize, starSize, starSize);
                star.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Additional note thank you for the Header Attribute i did not know about it gonna put it all over my code :D, also the generated stars looks cool now i have the feeling that i should develop some sci-fi game ^^

Comment: if `HeaderAttribute` changed your life that much then check this: `AddComponentMenuAttribute`

Comment: but I changed the code and I was instantiating the new star only if there is not overlap. So there is no current star at the moment. Still got the same problem tho :(

Comment: I tested this code 10 times and it produced no overlapping spheres!

Comment: @Menyus yes, I tried your too, it works. I don't get the differences tho xD

Comment: I will, when I found out why it doesn't work with the other version ^^ @Menyus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199477/discussion-between-menyus-and-bobby).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your starSize use both for local scale (multiple factor) and sphere collider (flat factor).  Eg: your star have default size of 2 and your starSize equal 2, then your actual radius of your sphere is 4, but your collider check for 2*0.5 + 2 = 3.

Comment: But I thouyt I was applying the scale after the check. So my star is at the check moment with always a scale of 1

EDIT : should I apply the scale divided by 0.5 ?

EDIT2 : Ok I don't quite get the scale problem sorry